# Define Array and Keys in a literal way - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, key-value

Trying to consolidate this...

```
string[] array = new string[];

array[0] = "Index 0";
array[3] = "Index 3";
array[4] = "index 4";
```

Into one line...

Example in PHP

```
$array = array( 0 => "Index 0", 3 => "Index 3", 4 => "Index 4" );
```

I know I can do this

```
string[] array = { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

But how would i get the proper indexes in there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're really after a `Dictionary<int, string>` rather than a traditional C# array:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 0, "Index 0" },
    { 3, "Index 3" },
    { 4, "Index 4" }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In C# you can't. If you wanted specific indexes you'd have to pass in `null` values to hold the place of the empty object.

It sounds like you're really after a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know, you can't skip index numbers in regular array (e.g. 0,1,2 and then 4 without 3). You need to use different data structure like Dictionary or Hashtable.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable()
{
    {"key1", "value1"},
    {"key2", "value2"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you cannot define arrays in the way you want. Other posters have indicated you can use associative arrays (Dictionaries)

At best you can create a workaround:

`string[] array = {"array0", "", "array2", "array3"};`

or

`string[] array = new string[4];
array[0] = "array0";
array[2] = "array2";`